# How can I make my script wait until a call to a function containing another function call has completed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have a script looking like this:

```
...
...
dotask(data1);
...
...   

doTask = function(data) {
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        it('test', function () {
            expect(longTask());
        });
    }
}
```

The expect function waits until `longTask()` is completed.

How can I make the call to `dotask()` to wait until everything is completed inside it?

Comment: Yes it is.  It's Jasmine, Selenium and Protractor.

Comment: i would look up jasmine-async.

Comment: I was thinking I might have to do my own promises. Yes I will look that up thanks.